# Calculating Attendance dates for Students using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need a little help with resolving a VBA code for an school assignment.

```
   Dim i As Long
    Dim LastStudent As Long

    Records.Sheets("Student").Activate
        LastStudent = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastStudent

        If (DateDiff("d", Date, Attendance_rng.Range("I" & i).Value) > 80) Then
           .Range("K15").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Attendance_rng.Range("A:A"), RollNo, Attendance_rng.Range("D:D"), "ACTIVE")
        End If
    Next
```

I tried to execute the above code snippet. I don't see any errors but I don't get any data output either.
I want to count the number of days (Today's date - date in column I for each student), if that value is > 80 then record the day count in cell K15 for each student(Roll Number) from column A where the G Column data is "Active".
Note:
Column I has the Weekly recorded attendance dates

Comment: You are over-writing K15 each time round your loop. you need to write the answer into a different cell each time

Comment: I take it you're not showing all your code - `.Range("K15")` is in a `With....End With` block?  `.CELLS(15,11)` also refers to cell K15 (row 15, column 11).  Try using `.CELLS(i,11)` which will replace the row number with the value of the `i` variable.

Comment: I need to get the total student count with attendance > 80 in one cell